# ruby regular expression (Removing characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am fetching some results from the database :

```
@log_detail = connection.execute("SELECT logs,setup FROM mastertest WHERE test_ins_id LIKE blah blah blah");
```

Results

```
 logs = a/atf/something
 setup = tb-1-atf with ac-2115
```

I want

```
logs = atf/something
setup = 2115
```

I tried the following for the logs, but it doesn't seem to work

```
@log_detail.each do |row|
    row[0] = row[0].drop(2) 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
row[0] = row[0][2..-1]
```

And have a look at the `[]` method on [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html).